# Strange behaviors of ActiveRecord in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord

I have to model with relation:

**Participation** has many **Passings**

In the test a got a strange thing:

```
participation.passings
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
participation.passings.to_sql
"SELECT \"passings\".* FROM \"passings\"  WHERE \"passings\".\"participation_id\" = $1  ORDER BY \"passings\".\"datetime\" ASC"
```

But:

```
Passing.where(participation: participation)
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Passing id: 8, chip_id: "0000001", datetime: "2016-05-05 07:28:53", detector_id: 1, event_id: 1, participation_id: 1, is_valid: false, location_id: nil, created_at: "2016-05-05 07:20:55", updated_at: "2016-05-05 07:20:55", gun_time: 0.0, split_time: 0.0, time: 0.0, raw_passing_id: 8, enabled: true>...]
```

I don't understand why when I call `participation.passings` I get empty collection if I make query through relation model - all OK.
In development environment both queries get equal result.

Comment: check, `participation.reload.passings` also validate participation: `participation.inspect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `participation.passings` is pulling cached data, rather than reloading the association from a DB query.

To see why this happens, suppose you have the following:

```
participation = Participation.create
new_passing = Passing.create(participation_id: participation.id)

participation.passings # Still an empty collection

participation.passings(true).pluck(:id) == [new_passing.id] # Now returns a collection including `new_passing`

# Can also reload the collection
participation.reload

participation.passings.pluck(:id) == [new_passing.id] # Should also be true
```

To fix, try forcing a reload by passing `true` to the `passings` association:

```
participation.passings(true)
```

If you include your tests, it may shed more light on the issue.